# Undefined symbol: boost::re_detail_106300::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>

Tags: macos, react-native, boost, cmake, react-native-ios

Undefined symbol: boost::re_detail_106300::cpp_regex_traits_implementation::transform_primary(char const*, char const*) const
I m trying to compile my project. I got the error stated that regex .

Comment: Just dropping an error message is definitely not sufficient for express your problem. You need to be more detailed about it.

Comment: In android build completely  Run in xcode build failed